# How to measure the time a packet spends on the system(router)?

Tags: networking, iptables, performance

I have a streaming system and one if its components is a router/firewall. I'm using `iptables` for setting the required behaviour on the router.

I'm having performance issues in forms of a constant multiple second lag on the destination computer where the stream is interpreted.

I would like to try to eliminate the routers processing time as the source of the lag.

Is there a way to measure the time a packet spends on the router?

Comment: could please be more precise in what you try to attemp

Comment: Try `traceroute` from a client to a computer that is behind the router. You should be able to tell how long it took the package to hop from one router to the next.

Comment: When you say *package* do you mean *[packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet)*?

Comment: @Kiwy Updated the question to try to make t more clear.

Comment: @derobert You are correct, fixed the expression.

Comment: If you could and think the routing is the problem, then you can maybe try by just bridging your network interfaces together it should reduce latency and allow you to identify whether the routing or something else responsible for the lag.

Comment: @Kiwy Thanks for the idea, unfortunately that scenario isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MTR (if you have it installed) to measure the ping between you and all the hops, with the plus that it also will diagnostic other common networking problems like packet loss:

```
Resolver error: No error returned but no answers given. of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 10.X.X.X                          0.0%    14    1.7   2.0   1.7   2.7   0.0
 2. ???
 3. x.x.x.x                           0.0%    13  108.2 125.9  85.7 205.1  30.9
 4. xx-x-x-x.XXX.MIA19.ALTER.NET      7.7%    13  144.2 151.6  77.7 215.2  36.1
 5. x.xx-x-x-x.XXX.MIA19.ALTER.NET   15.4%    13  135.2 140.9 104.2 165.4  20.2
 6. x.xx-x-x-x.XXX.ATL4.ALTER.NET     7.7%    13  194.9 172.6 100.1 208.6  32.4
 7. ae17.edge5.Atlanta2.level3.net    7.7%    13  191.9 176.4 139.2 219.5  25.6
 8. b.resolvers.Level3.net            0.0%    13  178.5 167.7 125.2 195.7  20.5
```

In my case the first host is my router. There is traceroute but the output is a bit more terse and complicated of interpret.